# Error when taking users profile picture and adding it to another image - discord.py

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

Im trying to make flower command. It should take the mentioned users profile picture and add it to the flower image but for some reason it doesnt work and i get an error below.

Image:
[image]

Error:

```
ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (251). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)
```

Code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 5.0, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def flower(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user == ctx.author
    flower = Image.open("flower.png")
    asset = user.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)

    pfp = pfp.resize(302,251)

    flower.paste(pfp,(822,114))

    flower.save("profile.png")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("profile.png"))
```

Comment: Did you already have the user image?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your call to `Image.resize` is wrong, you gave it parameters in a wrong way. The `Image.resize` function takes two parameters, one of which (`resample`) is optional:

`Image.resize(size, resample)`

Comment: I dont understand now, so there has to be only one value ?

Comment: size most likely is going to be in form `(x,y)` so `resize((x,y))`. You can also write `size=(x,y)` then `resize(size)`.

Comment: Your solution worked but i still dont understand why it didnt work. Like why using resize((100,100)) isnt the same as resize(size). Values are the same, im basically saying that i want to resize the image by size and size values are 100,100 so resize((100,100)) is basically the same thing.

Comment: @loa_in_ It actually takes [up to four](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) arguments; all but the first is optional, which expects a `tuple`. I think mentioning that `size` is a tuple would be a good thing to include in your answer, since missing that detail is the cause of OP's problem.

Comment: @ZeroKnight I gathered asker doesn't know what a tuple is, so I didn't mention it by name. I also don't have time to write tuple tutorials.

Comment: @garadosix To elaborate, `resize((x,y))` and `size=(x,y); resize(size)` are the same, however `resize(x,y)` is not. So the `size` is one value, but contains two things inside.